# shutdown hook won't start upon ^C (scala)

Tags: scala, shutdown-hook

i'm trying to get a clean and gracefull shutdown, and for some reason, it wont execute. iv'e tried:

```
sys addShutdownHook{
    logger.warn("SHUTTING DOWN...")
    // irrelevant logic here...
}
```

and also:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(ThreadOperations.delayOnThread{
        logger.warn("SHUTTING DOWN...")
        // irrelevant logic here...
    }
)
```

where `ThreadOperations.delayOnThread` definition is:

```
object ThreadOperations {

    def startOnThread(body: =>Unit) : Thread = {
        onThread(true, body)
    }

    def delayOnThread(body: =>Unit) : Thread = {
        onThread(false, body)
    }

    private def onThread(runNow : Boolean, body: =>Unit) : Thread = {
        val t=new Thread {
            override def run=body
        }
        if(runNow){t.start}
        t
    }

    // more irrelevant operations...
}
```

but when i run my program (executable jar, double activation), the hook does not start. so what am i doing wrong? what is the right way to add a shutdown hook in scala? is it in any way related to the fact i'm using double activation?

double activation is done like that:

```
object Gate extends App {
    val givenArgs = if(args.isEmpty){
                        Array("run")
                    }else{
                        args
                    }

    val jar = Main.getClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile;
    val dir = jar.dropRight(jar.split(System.getProperty("file.separator")).last.length + 1)
    val arguments = Seq("java", "-cp", jar, "boot.Main") ++ givenArgs.toSeq
    Process(arguments, new java.io.File(dir)).run();
}
```

(scala version: 2.9.2 )
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

For some reason, I thought that `run` as opposed to `!` would detach the process. It actually hangs on because there are open streams left to the `Process`, which is returned from `run` (or maybe it just hangs for another reason, 'cause `exec` doesn't hang, but returns a `Process` with open streams to and from the child process, much like `run`). For this reason, the original process was still alive, and I accidentally sent the signals to it. Of course, it did not contain a handler, or a shutdown hook, so nothing happened.

The solution was to use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(arguments.toArray)` instead of `Process(arguments, new java.io.File(dir)).run();`, close the streams in the `Gate` object, and send the ^C signal to the right process.

Answer (score 0):

In your second attempt, your shutdown hook you seems to just create a thread and never start it (so it just gets garbage collected and does nothing). Did I miss something? (EDIT: yes I did, see comment. My bad).

In the first attempt, the problem might just be that the underlying log has some caching, and the application exits before the log is flushed.

Comment: as to the second attamept, it is just syntactic sugar, and could have been written like that: `Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable(){override def run{...}}))` and as for the logging, i'm using the standart log4j, it's hard to believe that an issue like flushing was not taken care of... anyway, none of the other logic was executed.

Comment: My bad, I totally overlooked the fact that addShutdownHook takes a Thread, spoiled as am I with the pass by name construct of scala. I should have been more careful. As for the flushing issue, in my experience it is a very real problem. Even if log4j itself adds a shutdown hook to perform flushing at exit, its hook could very well be executed *before* your own hook. Howevern from what I understands log4j does not buffer *by default* so if you left the default configuration I guess this can't be a flushing problem.